# Error when importing numpy in Pycharm and Spyder under MacOS Monterrey

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pycharm

I'm trying to set up Pycharm with python 3.9.10 under MacOS Monterrey, but when I try to import `numpy` I got the following error, the same happens with Spyder. I'm not using anaconda and I tried uninstalling and updating `numpy` without success. Any clue how can I solve this issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3552, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-8-d4cdadb62aa7>", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    import numpy
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 144, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.
We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
Please note and check the following:
  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.22.3"
and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
Original error was: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
```